# View webm files with some quicktime plugin on El Capitan (Safari 9.0)?

Tags: safari, video, quicktime, macos

In Yosemite and earlier versions I used to be able to click on a webm file and the quicktime logo showed very quickly then the video started playing.

I think this is some sort of old plugin (like Flash Player), not extension (like Adblock), is there any way to get it back on El Capitan or does it not work anymore?